# Convert Local Phonegap App to Android App

Tags: cordova, phonegap, phonegap-cli

I need to convert my **Phonegap** files to an `Android` app using `CLI`. I don't need `Android Webview`.

How is that possible? Can someone help me, please? Thanks.